# HTML5 video, cue points, and stop points

Tags: javascript, video, jquery-plugins, html5-video

I've seen that there are a couple solutions for cuepoints for HTML5 video by wrapping the element in Javascript and triggering play at different times along the track with PopcornJS, CuepointsJS, etc.

But is there anything out there that not only allows for cuepoints on HTML5 video but also trigger stops too? Like what if I want to setup "chapters" along one video where I click a link that plays 0:25 to 0:45 and stops at 0:45? I want to have multiple cues and stops along 1 video, is there anything out there that makes this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some relatively simple code that I use to handle cuepoints. It lives in this gist (https://gist.github.com/positlabs/30605eccf05375da14f1)

```
/*

    // mapping cues to methods
    var cuepointMethods = {
        "1": function(){},
        "2.82": function(){},
        "3.31": function(){}
    };

    // instantiate with <video>, and an array of cuepoint times => [1, 2.82, 3.31]
    var cp = new CuePoints(document.querySelector('#video'), Object.keys(cuepointMethods));

    // listen for cue event
    cp.on('cue', function(cue){
        // do something with the cue
        // in this example, we map the cue to a method
        cuepointMethods[cue]();
    });

*/


window.CuePoints = function(video, cuepoints){

    this.video = video;
    this.cuepoints = cuepoints;

    video.addEventListener('play', this._onPlayVideo.bind(this));
    if(!video.paused) this._onPlayVideo();
};

// https://www.npmjs.com/package/backbone-events-standalone
CuePoints.prototype = BackboneEvents.mixin({});

CuePoints.prototype._onPlayVideo = function(){
    this._prevTime = this.video.currentTime;
    // start animationframe
    this._onFrame();
};

CuePoints.prototype._onFrame = function(){
    // only fire cue events if video is playing. Might not be wanted in some cases...
    if(this.video.paused) return;

    this.cuepoints.forEach(function(cuepoint){
        if(cuepoint >= this._prevTime && cuepoint < this.video.currentTime){
            this.trigger('cue', cuepoint);
        }
    }.bind(this));

    this._prevTime = this.video.currentTime;
    requestAnimationFrame(this._onFrame.bind(this));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 cue object has a property called '[pauseOnExit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/embedded-content-0.html#dom-texttrackcue-pauseonexit)' for this.

This feature is implemented in Chrome and Opera. You can use a polyfill like [webshims](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html) to implement this feature in all browsers.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/cTjaj/).

```
var cue = new TextTrackCue(0.5, 5, "My first Cue");
cue.pauseOnExit = true;
```

Comment: The "working example" is not working. Any update on that alexander farkas?